# Xamarin - Open new page without header

Tags: xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin.Forms app I open a new page on click on a button. For this I create a new NavigationPage and show it using Navigation.PushModalAsync(). This works perfectly but the newly opened page shows a header on the top with the logo of the app and the title of the page.

Is there a way to open a new page without that header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the page constructor:

```
NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I as well figured out that I could simply say "Navigation.PushModalAsync(myView);" without even using a NavigationPage.

Comment: Yes, PushModalAsync without NavigationPage will work fine too if you don't need to use navigation there.